# Why does the pattern matching return this result in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

Here are the codes I read in https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions

```
match = re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx1 2   3xx') =>  found, match.group() == "1 2   3"

match = re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx12  3xx') =>  found, match.group() == "12  3"

match = re.search(r'\d\s*\d\s*\d', 'xx123xx') =>  found, match.group() == "123"
```

I understand that `\d\s*\d\s*\d` will match 1 2   3, but I do not know why `\d\s*\d\s*\d` and `\d\s*\d\s*\d` can also match 12  3 and 123 respectively?

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Litterally, '\d\s*\d\s*\d' means a "a single digit followed by any number of whitespaces followed by a single digit followed by any number of whitespaces followed by a single digit"

Since 0 is "any" number, your regex matches 12 3 and 123 without problem. If you want a regex thqt matches 1 2 3 but not 12 3 nor 123, try '\d\s+\d\s+\d'.

Answer (score 1):

The '*'  after the \s will match zero to many whitespace characters